# Find input using document.querySelectorAll and innerHTML problem

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, selectors-api

I use the "document.querySelectorAll" method in order to find an input. The first code where I use: "input[type=text]", I do find the input and can set the value as shown in code.

However, I have many inputs with "type=text" and want to also find the input by determine that the innerHTML contains: "searchFilter.fromDate"

I have tried the below code but the code doesn't work. I wonder if I do this incorrectly and how I can do it?

```js
            //THE INPUT TO FIND
            //<input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-date ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-parse ng-touched" 
            //ng-model="searchFilter.fromDate" placeholder="From Date" bs-datepicker="" ng-disabled="inProgress()" style="">


            //This code finds the input
            String select = "document.querySelectorAll('" + "input[type=text]" + "')";
            String clickinputscript1 = select + "[0].value = '1231';"; //Script that is executed

            //This code does NOT find the input
            //How can I search the inputs innerHTML after "searchFilter.fromDate" in order to find this input?
            String select2 = "document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]').map(input => input.innerHTML).filter(txt => txt.includes('searchFilter.fromDate')";
            String clickinputscript2 = select2 + "[0].value = '1232';"; //Script that is executed
```

Comment: please show the html code

Comment: @brk I beleive the html code is in the code example for the input control

Comment: Please click Edit and then "Edit above snippet" and post a [mcve] Your code and html does not make any sense

Comment: If this is actually AngularJS, then add an AngularJS tag.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `document.querySelectorAll('[ng-model="searchFilter.fromDate"]')`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')` will return a NodeList, not an array. A NodeList doesn't have a `.map` method, so the second piece of code should be throwing a TypeError saying "map is not a function".

Comment: @ mplungjan This actually worked. I wonder if it would be possible to specify it even further to include that it must search for an input first before, something like this but this doesn't work: <code>document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text] > [ng-model="searchFilter.fromDate"]')</code>

Comment: @ VLAZ, document.querySelectorAll('input[ng-model="searchFilter.fromDate"]') Thank you all very much for the help. This seems to work out!